# Hapijs Forwarding a stream to another server

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, nodejs-stream

I try to upload a image to my Hapijs Server via stream and send(pipe) the data to another Hapijs instance.

So I have this post Route, which should receive a stream and forward it:

```
 this.server.route({
            method: "POST",
            path: RouteManager.Routes.SearchRoute.User.Icon.post,
            config: {
                payload: {
                    output: 'stream',
                    parse: true,
                    allow: 'multipart/form-data',
                    maxBytes: 4194304 //4MB
                },
                handler: (request, reply) => {
                    const data = request.payload.image;
                    const req = require("request").post("myOtherServer.com" + "/upload",
                    {
                      formData: {
                        image: data
                    }
                }, (err, httpResp, body) => {
                    cb(err, JSON.parse(body));
                });
                }
            }
        })
```

My route on the other Server looks like this:

```
 this.hapi.route({
            method: 'POST',
            path: Routes.index.child.upload.post,
            config: {
                payload: {
                    output: 'stream',
                    parse: true,
                    allow: 'multipart/form-data',
                    maxBytes: 4194304 //4MB
                }
                }
            },
            handler: (request, reply) => {       
                    this.workWithStream(request, reply);
            }
        });
```

When i run the code i get always this response:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Invalid multipart payload format"
}
```

How is it possible to forwarding a stream to another hapijs server(without to save a temporary file)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing that the plugin [h2o2](https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2) can be used for.

Register it like you would any other plugin:

```
server.register({
    register: require('h2o2')
}, function (err) {

    if (err) {
        console.log('Failed to load h2o2');
    }

    server.start(function (err) {

        console.log('Server started at: ' + server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

Then the following route will get you started with forwarding a stream to your other server:

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/upload',
    config: {
        payload: {
            output: 'stream',
            parse: false,
            allow: 'multipart/form-data',
            maxBytes: 4194304
        },
        auth: false
    },
    handler: {
        proxy: {
            host: 'your.remote.server',
            port: 'your-remote-port',
            protocol: 'http'
        }
    }
}
```

For proxying to work, `parse` has to be set to `false` on the proxy server, but can be set to `true` on the server that's actually processing your file.

For this example to work, the paths on both servers must be the same.